# Catch errors when creating a Hyper-V VM with Powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, hyper-v

Is there any way to catch an error when creating a new Hyper-V VM with Powershell?

```
New-VM -Name $vmname `
 -MemoryStartupBytes $memorySize `
 -Path D:\Hyper-V\ `
 -NewVHDPath D:\Hyper-V\$vmname\$vmname.vhdx `
 -NewVHDSizeBytes $diskSize `
 -Generation 2 `
 -SwitchName "vSwitch"
```

As far as I can see, there is no way to add -ErrorAction Stop to New-VM.

Errors can occur, for example, if the virtual switch does not exist. In this case no further tasks should be processed and the script should be terminated.

Comment: Maybe check for resource existence before trying to create the vm?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that `-ErrorAction Stop` cannot be used? Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/new-vm?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters), `New-VM` supports _common parameters_, which do include `-ErrorAction`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The main reason is that when you delete the VM, the folders still remain (usually). Then when I run the script again, it fails because the folder exists.

Yes one option would be to first check if the folder exists, however a simpler option like ErrorAction would be better for me. 

I have tried ErrorAction Stop, but it does not stop the run.

Comment: How does `New-VM` report an error then? Please add any error message to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are saying is not error. You have to have a conditional check. I have given a rough skeleton for you to proceed along with error handling:

```
try ##runs everything in the try block to capture and error in the catch block
{

        If(Get-VM -Name $vmname) ##checks if the VM is existing or not by fetching the VM information. It has further parameters. Kindly google about them for better understanding
        {
            "$vmname is already present"
        }
        else
        { 
        ## Only creates the VM when it doesnt exist
            New-VM -Name $vmname `
             -MemoryStartupBytes $memorySize `
             -Path D:\Hyper-V\ `
             -NewVHDPath D:\Hyper-V\$vmname\$vmname.vhdx `
             -NewVHDSizeBytes $diskSize `
             -Generation 2 `
             -SwitchName "vSwitch"
        }
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message   ## Only captures the error exception message and not the entire error.
}
```

I have given explanations in the Comment block for you to understand it better.